# Chrome extension hide webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification notification balloon with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, notifications, google-chrome-extension

How to hide Chrome extension notification balloons with JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

`window.close()` (assuming you are running it inside notification html)

Answer (score 2):

```
notification.cancel();
```

I used it in my Chrome extension.